# How do I monitor and limit the number of QueueBackgroundWorkItem threads in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have an ASP.Net application acting as an interface between systems which tend to send data in bursts via multiple requests and I would like to kick off a background task to perform some processing but would really like to only have one single background task do it. I can use HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem but that will indiscriminately launch a thread for each incoming request which is a problem.

When I launch a background process I want it to queue up the work it has (in the connected database) and then check if there is another background process running. If there is then it should finish because the other process will process the queued work. If there is no other background process running then I want it to start processing the queued work until there is no more to do and then it will stop.

The process is not a heavy task or long running task but the main constraint is that everything is processed in a strict order making parallel threading risky. In a single process it's easy to ensure everything gets processed in order.

How do I achieve this without shifting to an external service?

Comment: Note, that you will never be able to completely prevent background work from being lost. There can be redeployments, reboots, bluescreens, power losses, or simply bugs.

Comment: There's a lot of status tracking in the database. It's impossible to lose or corrupt any data no matter what happens to the processes.

Comment: Good. Then you can use a simpler architecture. No need for QueueBackgroundWorkItem. You can, for example, have a permanent thread/task that drains a BlockingCollection of work. Would that work? That saves you the trouble of starting and stopping threads/tasks.

Comment: BlockingCollection looks interesting at first glance. I can see that I have a bit of reading to do :) Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a classic producer consumer scenario. Create a BlockingCollection that producers enqueue to. Create one permanent `LongRunning` `Task` that drains that collection.

You can drain in batches if you want.

This would not work with `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` because the you need to eventually exit the work that you put into `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` so that the worker process can shutdown gracefully.

Comment: Marking as answer. While I don't need the BlockingCollection's queue management functionality searching for it did direct me to the range of "Concurrent" classes in the same namespace (System.Collections.Concurrent). I can pretty much use any one of them to handle thread to thread communications. I can code the threads to organise themselves :-)